# Changing ip addresses of multiple servers

Tags: ansible, ip-address

I have set of servers which are moving to another network. I have a file which has hostnames and corresponding new IP addresses
.
I looked across how to achieve this using Ansible but that requires unique playbook for each server. Tried to script it but same issue.

Can someone suggest eg. how to change the IP address of 2+ servers from an external server assuming you can login as root.

Ansible playbook is preferred.

Comment: Why do you think this requires a different playbook for each server? You can loop through variables aswell as servers. Look into `host_vars`

Comment: @Panki has it -- just add a `new_ip` host var for each host, then use the playbook to change them.

Comment: Or a script: `for s in LIST-OF-SERVERS; do ssh $s ip a add NEWADDR/PREFIX dev NIC; ssh $s ip a del OLDADDR/PREFIX dev NIC; done`. This assumes it's the same NIC for all servers.

Comment: This is the disadvantage of fixed IP addresses, and one of the reasons `DHCP` was invented. You should configure your servers to get their IP addresses via `DHCP`.

Comment: @waltinator I would say that giving IP addresses to servers through DHCP is poor practice. Client workstations, sure, but servers... "just say no". (Obviously it depends on the environment, but if someone's using Ansible it's unlikely they're a small outfit.)

Comment: @Shadur - Thanks for the pointers. This idea looks promising. If you don't mind to share a snippet as an example for usage of "host_vars" and "new_ip" - will be great starter for me.

Comment: @Panki  - Thanks for the pointers. This idea looks promising. If you don't mind to share a snippet as an example for usage of "host_vars" and "new_ip" - will be great starter for me.

Comment: Looks like @panki got there before me.

Comment: @roima: You can do DHCP for servers by setting up a fixed mapping from the server's MAC address to the server's IP address, as long as the IP address is outside the range the DHCP server allocates from. You could, for security reasons, have 0 IP addresses in the range, and all fixed MAC to IP mappings. Thus, a "stranger" attaching  to the server LAN won't get an IP address, and will be hindered in attacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have `serverA`, `serverB` and `serverC` in our inventory. They need new IP adresses.

So the first step is to create a file in your `host_vars` directory named like your server, and write the new IP adress as a variable into that.

Example with file `host_vars/serverA`:

```
new_ip: 10.1.0.27
```

Do the same for `serverB` and `serverC` with their corresponding adresses. You can also extend this to the network interface names, if needed.

Next, create a playbook which uses the previously defined variables. The `ip` module shown in this command does not exist, I am only demonstrating use of the variable here. See the [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/) if there is a module that fits your needs, otherwise use `command`/`shell`.

```
- name: Change IP
    hosts: serverA serverB serverC
    become: yes
    tasks:
      - name: Set new IP adress
        ip: "{{ new_ip }}"
        interface: eth0
```

Also, be prepared to lose connection from `ansible`. [This question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299910/7360830) shows how to handle that and keep the connection running.